# Python can't get two separate programs to work together version related

Tags: python

I have a tkinter program that works fine in 3.3.1 but won't even bring up a separate window in 2.7.4.  Very simple program to bring up a window and do some drawing on the screen.  Either way:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x600+0+0')


from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x600+0+0')
```

Neither way works in 2.7.4 to bring up the new window.  In 3.3.1 it works fine when I get the capitalization correct.

A simpler problem comes up when I try to run this next program in 3.3.1:

```
import os
import sys
a = open('datafile.txt','r')
b = a.readlines()
a.close()
c = len(b)
d = zip(*(e.split() for e in b))
f = d[0]
```

I get the error ' zip' object is not subscriptable.  I don't get that error when using 2.7.4.

I'm trying to combine two programs and this is where I'm running into stumbling blocks.  I can run both programs separately in their respective version of python but when I put them together for some reason I'm unable to run them in either version of python.

What gives?  I think I would tend to much rather be using 2.7.4 so I would much rather off get the subscriptable error eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.x and 3.x are not fully compatible. `zip` in Python 3 returns an iterable object; use `list(zip(...))` to make it subscriptable.

To switch between different imports by version (i.e. the capitalisation issue) use

```
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
```

Comment: For 3.3.1 this works perfect.  Thanks.  Still not sure which version I prefer especially since both 2.7 and 3.3 are both still being worked on.  Now that I just reread what you wrote I fully understand the second bit of code now.  I had to look at it more carefully.